# input[max] for validation does not work

Tags: jquery

Html Code:

```
<input type='number' name='input_name_here' max='10' placeholder='Enter a number less than 10'>

$('input[max]').each(function()
{
  maxValue=$(this).attr("max");
  inputValue=$(this).val();
  if(inputValue>maxValue)
    alert("Please consider the Maximum permited value");
});
```

But this does not work. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Are you aware of what you are doing?

Comment: Can you please show us your html that goes with this jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the html line. Can you explain what is not working? Can you confirm if it enters the loop at all with an alert or something?

Comment: @user2338488: It seems it doesn't enter the each function. I just placed a dummy alert inside the each, that alert does not appear at all.

Comment: working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/9Q3Wd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in your logic.

`$('input[max]').each(function()` will work fine for inputs with `max` attribute. If your code does not enter the `each` part, you need to check the rest part of the jQuery code.

I have made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qM37j/1/) with your code, have a look at it. That actually works. And for mathematical inputs, you are advised to include `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, so as to omit errors in validation.

Comment: yeah, the fiddle works as i expect. Will dig in to my javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i thought you were doing this

```
<input type="" max="50" name="max" value="100">


$('input[name="max"]').each(function()
{
  var maxValue=$(this).attr("max");
  var inputValue=$(this).val();
  alert(maxValue);alert(inputValue);
  if(inputValue>maxValue)
    {
      alert("yes");
    }
});
```

Comment: Will be better if you used `input.max` (with class max) instead of `input[name="max"]`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using data- attribute

use like below:

```
    $("input").find("[data-max='" + current + "']");
```